# Conditional in Powershell Output

Tags: powershell

I am running the below piece of code to get stats from our Storage Unit. I would like to display the output only if the Operation Status is not 'OK'or Health Status is not 'Healthy'. I am not sure how to add this to the code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
$Storage = Get-PhysicalDisk -Manufacturer Storage | Select FriendlyName, FirmwareVersion, PhysicalLocation, OperationalStatus, HealthStatus, @{n='Size (TB)';e={[math]::Round($_.size/1tb,2)}} | ConvertTo-Html
Write-Output $Storage
write-host "\nMessage: $Storage";
write-host "\nStatistic: 0";
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to filter as early as possible.

Preferably that would be using the `-HealthStatus` parameter of `Get-PhysicalDisk`, but since there's nothing similar for OperationalStatus, I'd just filter in pipeline for simplicity.

e.g. (untested)

```
$Storage = Get-PhysicalDisk -Manufacturer Storage |
    Where-Object {($_.OperationalStatus -ne "OK") -or ($_.HealthStatus -ne "Healthy")} |
    Select-Object FriendlyName, FirmwareVersion, PhysicalLocation, OperationalStatus, HealthStatus, @{n='Size (TB)';e={[math]::Round($_.size/1tb,2)}} |
    ConvertTo-Html

Write-Output $Storage
write-host "\nMessage: $Storage";
write-host "\nStatistic: 0";
```

Comment: You don't need the parens because of operator precedence.  `where-object {$_.OperationalStatus -ne "OK" -or $_.HealthStatus -ne "Healthy"}`

Comment: @js2010 agreed, just a readability choice

Comment: I was wondering if we can use an if statement, if OK or Healthy write-host "\nStatistic: 0" or write-host "\nStatistic: 1" Any ideas. I need a different Statistics Output if everything is OK or healthy.

Comment: Tried this and did not work ```` $Storage = Get-PhysicalDisk -Manufacturer Storage | Select FriendlyName, FirmwareVersion, PhysicalLocation, OperationalStatus | ConvertTo-Html
Write-Output $Storage
If ($_.OperationalStatus -notcontains "OK" -or $_.HealthStatus -notcontains "Healthy")
{
 write-host "$Storage";
 write-host "1";
}
else
{
 write-host "Operational Status is Healthy";
 write-host "0";
} ````

Comment: $_ is the pipeline object, why are you using it outside of a pipe? Why are you looking for results where none of the drives are ok rather than having any fails? I'd suggest updating the question with new requirements.